# Querying "Pepper Public API" with requests

Tags: rest, python-requests

I'm trying to query the [HotUKDeals API](https://www.hotukdeals.com/docs/api.html). The page says

> This API follow some of the REST idioms.
>
> It is available under the https://{hostname}/rest_api/v2 root URI.

At the top of the page, it says

> https://www.pepper.com/rest_api/v2

So I have tried writing

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.pepper.com/rest_api/v2')
r.status_code
```

as per the [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). However, this returns `404`.

Does this mean that the HotUKDeals API isn't working, or am I making a mistake in querying it?

Disclaimer: I've been using Python for couple of years but am a `requests` noob.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that this Api does only gives you 200s to actual querys. (You need to add something behind v2 as mentioned in the docs)